# CSS Gradient not working on all bootstrap button classes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is HTML CODE

`````````````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Assignment1_2</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "css/assignment3.css">
  <!----I used indexing using class names from K-K1 in css stylesheet-->
</head>
<body>
       <div class="container" id="K2">
           <div class="row my-5 py-5 mx-2 px-2">
               <span class="d-xl-block w-100 mx-4 pt-5 pb-4 K1">
                    <div class="container pt-3 ml-3">
                        <div class="row pb-0 pt-5" >
                             <div class="col-md-3"> 
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info K">Buy Now</button>
                             </div>
                             <div class="col-md-9">
                                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info K">Larger Button To Test that
                                        we did it correctly.
                                 </button>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </span>
           </div> 
       </div>
</body>
</html>


````````````
this is CSS for that
```````````
#K2 .K{background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.4), rgba(255,255,255,0)); 
    border-radius: 60px; border-style: none}
#K2 .K1{
  margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -2.5px;
  background-color: #a5aab1;
  border-radius: 14px
  }
`````````````

[This is the button style I am supposed to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOf3X.png)

My Problem actually is I want to change button color. And want color like CYAN and it should have top to bottom gradient. But Its not working when I use btn-cyan bootstrap class it is not working. [This is where I found about btn-cyan class](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/components/buttons/)
Also exact color which I am supposed to use is  "HTML code: #0C8BCB
RGB code:   R: 12 G: 139 B: 203". But when I enter these values in the CSS linear gradient tag. It is not working. I tried removing that btn-info tag and keeping it also. but it didnt work.
Please add explanation also why it is not working and logic behind your answer and I apologize for my noobness.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement you will need to add **linear-gradient** property for your css gradient to work. Please see the code. As per your requirement I have used **#0C8BCB** color to enhance the button.

```css
.btn-info{
background:linear-gradient(#71d5e2,#0C8BCB );

}
```

```html
This is HTML CODE

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Assignment1_2</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "css/assignment3.css">
  <!----I used indexing using class names from K-K1 in css stylesheet-->
</head>
<body>
       <div class="container" id="K2">
           <div class="row my-5 py-5 mx-2 px-2">
               <span class="d-xl-block w-100 mx-4 pt-5 pb-4 K1">
                    <div class="container pt-3 ml-3">
                        <div class="row pb-0 pt-5" >
                             <div class="col-md-3"> 
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info K">Buy Now</button>
                             </div>
                             <div class="col-md-9">
                                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info K">Larger Button To Test that
                                        we did it correctly.
                                 </button>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </span>
           </div> 
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove unwanted codes from your css. and id not allowing to show your style.. just try like this

**css**

```
.container button{
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.4), rgba(255,255,255,0)); 
    border-radius: 60px; 
    border-style: none;
    }
.container .K1{
  margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -2.5px;
  background-color: #a5aab1;
  border-radius: 14px
  }
```